# Convertir una lista a un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo esta lista multiple

```
[['1', '228', '149'], ['2', '288', '129'], ['3', '270', '133'], ['4', '256', '141'], ['5', '256', '157'], ['6', '246', '157'], ['7', '236', '169'], ['8', '228', '169'], ['9', '228', '161']
```

Y quiero que el resultado sea este dentro de un diccionario, para poder sacar la pendiente despues con estas ubicaciones. Ejemplo -> {1:(x1,y1), 2:(x2, y2), ...}

```
{1:(228,149), 2:(228,129), 3:(270,133),....., 9:(228, 161)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma iterativa tradicional sería hacer algo así:

```
lista = [['1', '228', '149'], ['2', '288', '129'], ['3', '270', '133'], ['4', '256', '141'], ['5', '256', '157'], ['6', '246', '157'], ['7', '236', '169'], ['8', '228', '169'], ['9', '228', '161']]

dic = dict()
for e in lista:
  dic[int(e[0])] = (int(e[1]), int(e[2]))

print(dic)
```

Iteramos por cada elemento (sublista) de `lista` y vamos construyendo el diccionario, a partir de los 3 valores que lo componen. Por otro lado, tenemos la "comprensión" de listas que elabora una mecánica para entender lo mismo, pero mucho más compacta:

```
dic = {int(e[0]):(int(e[1]), int(e[2])) for e in lista}
print(dic)
```

En ambos casos la salida:

```
{1: (228, 149), 2: (288, 129), 3: (270, 133), 4: (256, 141), 5: (256, 157), 6: (246, 157), 7: (236, 169), 8: (228, 169), 9: (228, 161)}
```